# how does cs50's copy.c file actually find the correct part of the bitmap file?

Tags: c, bmp, cs50

After a long period of procrastination, I am back to finishing week 3 of cs50x2019 - but realize that I forgot some of the bitmap stuff from the whodunit exercise so I need to study up before continuing on resize.

I'm having some trouble understanding how copy.c is actually finding the relevant portion of the bmp file in order to do it's work.

Here's the relevant part of their code -

```
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;
    fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
    fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);
```

as far as I understand, here they are creating pointers and storing either all of the input file there or just the specific part.

```
// ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
    if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 ||
        bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
```

and here they are checking the structs according to bmp.h to ensure that everything is fine before continuing.

But, how and where are they saying which part of the bitmap file is being stored?

and if they aren't, then are bf.bftype and bi.bftype equivalent?

is there a need for having both bf and bi?

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious.

full copy.c below

```
// Copies a BMP file

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "bmp.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: copy infile outfile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // remember filenames
    char *infile = argv[1];
    char *outfile = argv[2];

    // open input file
    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return 2;
    }

    // open output file
    FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
    if (outptr == NULL)
    {
        fclose(inptr);
        printf("Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
        return 3;
    }

    // read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;
    fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
    fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
    if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 ||
        bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
    {
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        printf("Unsupported file format.\n");
        return 4;
    }

    // write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    fwrite(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    fwrite(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // determine padding for scanlines
    int padding = (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

    // iterate over infile's scanlines
    for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(bi.biHeight); i < biHeight; i++)
    {
        // iterate over pixels in scanline
        for (int j = 0; j < bi.biWidth; j++)
        {
            // temporary storage
            RGBTRIPLE triple;

            // read RGB triple from infile
            fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

            // write RGB triple to outfile
            fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
        }

        // skip over padding, if any
        fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);

        // then add it back (to demonstrate how)
        for (int k = 0; k < padding; k++)
        {
            fputc(0x00, outptr);
        }
    }

    // close infile
    fclose(inptr);

    // close outfile
    fclose(outptr);

    // success
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A BMP file has 4 distinct sections, they follow each other sequentially in the file so nothing dramatic needs to happen to read/write them.  The file header is first, the bfType field provides a basic check that this is actually a BMP file and not just a file with the wrong filename extension.  The info header is next, it describes basic properties of the bitmap like biBitCount.  It does not have a bfType field.  The color table is next, not programmed here because a 24bpp image doesn't have one.  Finally the bytes that describe the pixels, simplistic here because the code only support 24bpp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To steal from  Gaga: defined that way.

> But, how and where are they saying which part of the bitmap file is
>   being stored?

The first `fread` is reading the first `sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)` bytes, which is 14 by Microsoft's definition and `BITMAPFILEHEADER` definition in `bmp.h`

The second `fread` reads the next `sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)` bytes, which is 40 bytes by the same definitions.

> and if they aren't, then are bf.bftype and bi.bftype equivalent?

There is no `bi.bftype`.

> is there a need for having both bf and bi?

Absolutely. There is different info stored in each struct.

Perhaps study how this picture from the spec corresponds to `bmp.h`

[image: bmp file layout]

And don't forget to visit the Microsoft links in `bmp.h` as suggested in the spec.

Addenda:

> Is the only reason the code is able to accurately pull the relevant
>   bites because 'fread' remembers the position in the file?

Precisely!

Comment: Still having trouble understanding. 

`
  BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;
    fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);

    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
    fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);
`

Both of these define different variables of diff sizes, 14 and 37 as you pointed out. 

And the input is from the same file 'inptr'

Is the only reason the code is able to accurately pull the relevant bites because 'fread' remembers the position in the file?

Otherwise, how does it know which 14 & 37 bytes to look for?

Comment: Yes, 'fread' is the key, answer amended. (And BITMAPINFOHEADER is more like 40 bytes (14 to 53 inclusive), too early for maths :)